# How to set decimal precision dynamically using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting-services, decimal

I am trying to set decimal precision dynamically in a stored procedure like as below

```
 DECLARE @precison int
 select @precison = [ConfigValue] from [TestData] WHERE ConfigName = 'Precision'
 select CAST( (10.56/10.25)as decimal(18, @precision))
```

If precision is '2' SP should return '1.03' as result.But cast function is not accepting @precision parameter as variable .I want to return data as decimal itself from stored procedure.How can i achieve this in SQL Server

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? That value will be returned to the client where precision doesn't really matter. Are you trying to *truncate* or round the result perhaps?

Comment: You can't, not without dynamic SQL; and then the variable will only have scope inside the dynamic statement. This, however, smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: As for why you can't change the precision, SQL is more or less a  strongly typed language. Types and precisions matter a *lot* as they can lead to data losses or accidental truncations. The query engine has to be able to validate that the query won't perform invalid operations, which is impossible without knowing the type sizes

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos ..it is for reporting purpose

Comment: Which means you have no use for precision at all. The reporting tool does, and can easily control its own display format. This is definitely an XY problem. Whatever reporting tool you use, you can specify the precisions or display formats of individual fields quite easily

Comment: Instead of formatting eachand every expresssion in Report,it will be better if formatted data is send through SP

Comment: *"it will be better if formatted data is send through SP"* No the opposite is true. Formatting is for the presentation layer to do, not the RDBMS. That's why it's called the **presentation** layer; it's determining how to best *present* the data to the end user.

Comment: I have 50 expression in SSRS report..It will be good if we can do anything in DB side

Comment: You are doing things in the DBMS, you're getting the data. Then the report, the **presentation** layer, is presenting that data in the format you want. The formatting of those cells in the report should be done in SSRS, using the format property of the cell.

Comment: Purpose is number of decimal precison may change dynamically based on user request,So it will be updated in config table based on requirenment.SP will read precision value from config table and will format it and will return data

Comment: *"Purpose is number of decimal precison may change dynamically based on user request"* Then amend the formatting dynamic in the SSRS report...

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/dynamic-decimal-precision  It may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you have entirely the wrong idea. Formatting of data should be handled in the Presentation layer (in this case SSRS) *not* the RDBMS. Though you *could* dynamic declare something with a dynamic precision or scale, you would have to use dynamic SQL and that could severely overly complicate the matter and would likely break your SSRS report unless you understand how you implement dynamic statements successfully into SSRS.

Instead, you should be using the presentation layer to determine the formatting. This isn't particularly easy in SSRS, but it's also not difficult. Lets *assume* you have a parameter, `Precision`, in your SSRS report, which is defined as an `Integer`. I'm also going to use a basic data set from the below SQL:

```sql
SELECT d
FROM (VALUES(10),(10.1),(10.12),(10.123),(10.1234))V(d);
```

This means you might have a report that looks a little like this:

[image]

Right click the blank space, and select Report Properties and go to the Code pane. Then enter the below code:

```vb
Public Function DynamicPrecision(ByVal Precision AS Integer) AS String

    Dim I AS Integer
    If Precision = 0
        DynamicPrecision = "#,#"
    Else
        DynamicPrecision = "#,#."
        For I = 1 to Precision
            DynamicPrecision = DynamicPrecision & "0"
        Next I
    End If
End Function
```

Now click your cell (or hold control and click the cells) you want the dynamic precision on and then press F4 to open the properties pane. Fine Format in the Properties Pane and then then drop down and select "«expression»". Then enter the following expression:

```vb
=Code.DynamicPrecision(Parameters!Precision.Value)
```

Your cell will then dynamic format to that precision.

So, for `0`,`2`, and `4`, the data would look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thaks for detailed explaination..I will try this

Comment: Is any advantage over FormatNumber..like =FormatNumber(Fields!Test.Value,Parameters!DecimalPrecision.Value)

Comment: I find setting the formatting of the cell is more reliable than changing the formatting the the value (and turning it into a string) @vmb .

Comment: FormatNumber will convert it to string ? it will consider data a s string if we exporting result to excel?

Comment: Possibly, but my point doesn't change, why format is as a string, instead of changing the format of the cell? The cell has a format property for a reason; to define the property of said cell.

Answer (score 1):

ROUND and then FORMAT.  eg

```
 DECLARE @precison int = 2
 select format(round( (10.56/10.25),  @precison),'#,####.##')
```

Or just ROUND and let the front-end pick the display format.

Comment: This does, however, mean that a `varchar` is passed to the presentation layer. I hope the OP isn't doing any aggregation or expressions and expecting a numerical data types. `'1,000.00' + '123.00'` equals either an error or `'1,000.00123.00'`.

Comment: @David..it should pass as decimal itself to the presentation layer..i thoink above solution passing it as string

Comment: Then just ROUND to the desired number of decimal places.  Dynamically changing the data type of the return data is not necessaray.

Comment: SELECT ROUND( 10.9999/10.456, 2) will return 1.0500000000..But what i need is result should return "1.05"

Comment: "1.05" is a string.  .NET (and thus SSRS) doesn't have any data type that can distinguish between a 1.05 as a decimal(10,2) and 1.05 as a decimal(10,5), as .NET has a single decimal data type.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier,it is for a reorting purpose and data should be displayed in front end same as that it returned from SP

Comment: Then that's a string.  Because numbers returned from the database don't have a display format.